# Find top level functions in R file

Tags: r, metaprogramming

I come from a python background and am trying to get up to speed with R, so please bear with me

I have an R file - `util.R` with the following lines

```
util.add <- function(a,b) a + b
util.sub <- function(a,b) {
    a - b
}
```

I need to write a function that returns the following:

> findFunctions('path/util.R')

`[1] "util.add" "util.sub"`

Comment: Is the assumption that `util.R` has already been run so that the functions defined in it are part of your current environment, or do you want to go into the file and find any functions defined therein before running it?

Comment: The latter case i.e. any file and find functions. I would be open to sourcing it if there were no other options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think sourcing will be necessary, but you don't need to clutter you global environment. I tested this locally and it seems to work:

```
find_functions = function(file) {
    search_env = new.env()
    source(file = file, local = search_env)
    objects = ls(envir = search_env)
    functions = objects[sapply(ls(envir = search_env), FUN = function(x) {
        is.function(get(x, envir = search_env))
    })]
    return(functions)
}
```

Comment: On the money! Is there some way to go the other way around? i.e. given a sourced function object, retrieve the file it is defined in? I created a separate question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32747242/find-the-source-file-containing-r-function-definition

Comment: Probably not. R keeps track of the environment things are defined in, but if you look at the source of `source()` it just reads in the file with `readLines` and evaluates and parses it one line at a time. After all the lines are parsed the result is identical whether you sourced it locally or typed it in the console. If you have list of candidate files you could run `find_functions` on them and look for matches.

Comment: Hmm. It would've been useful to add it as an attribute to the function object. I guess as an alternative, I could write a custom source function that does this i.e. adds the source file path into sourced functions

Comment: You may just want to go to writing packages. With `devtools` and `roxygen2` it's quite easy to write a simple package, and then this question is as simple as looking at the package namespace and your comment question is the result of the built-in `findFunction()`.

Comment: See, e.g. `findFunction(f = "lm")`, but it will only be useful if the function is in a package.

Comment: It is already added as an attribute the function object, it's just hard to find.  See my answer to your other question.