# Find the source file containing R function definition

Tags: r, metaprogramming

I come from a python background and am trying to get up to speed with R, so please bear with me

I have an R file - `util.R` with the following lines:

```
util.add <- function(a,b) a + b
util.sub <- function(a,b) { a - b }
```

I source it as follows:

`source('path/util.R')`

I now have two function objects and want to write a function as follows:

> getFilePath(util.add)

that would give me this result

`[1] "path/util.R"`

Comment: Maybe wait until your previous question is answered before posting another...

Comment: IMO the two questions are independent

Comment: This might be difficult or somewhat hacky in R. If you describe in more detail why you might want to do this, perhaps some experienced R folks might be able to suggest a different approach.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Digging into the `srcref` attribute of one of the loaded functions appears to work, if you go deep enough ...

```
source("tmp/tmpsrc.R")
str(util.add)
## function (a, b)  
##  - attr(*, "srcref")=Class 'srcref'  atomic [1:8] 1 13 1 31 13 31 1 1
##   .. ..- attr(*, "srcfile")=Classes 'srcfilecopy', 'srcfile' <environment: 0x8fffb18> 
srcfile <- attr(attr(util.add,"srcref"),"srcfile")
ls(srcfile)
## [1] "Enc"           "filename"      "fixedNewlines" "isFile"       
## [5] "lines"         "parseData"     "timestamp"     "wd"    
srcfile$filename
## [1] "tmp/tmpsrc.R"
```

Comments note that this only works out-of-the-box for interactive code, because ...

> Rscript does not load srcrefs by default. A work-around is this code snippet: `Rscript -e "options(keep.source = TRUE); source('your_main_file.R')"` or set the option `keep.source` permanently in the `.Rprofile` file (see `?Startup` for details)

Comment: Fantastic, there is even a srcfile$wd for the relative paths!

Comment: @Ben, this only seems to work in interactive mode. Not when I do R with -e option or Rscript. Any idea how to get it to work for the additional conditions? Thanks

Comment: Don't know, offhand -- sorry.   Maybe edit your code/offer a bounty to draw attention to this new issue?  Or ask another question?

Comment: @user1827356 `Rscript` does not load `srcref`s by default. A work-around is this code snippet: `Rscript -e "options(keep.source = TRUE); source('your_main_file.R')"` or set the option `keep.source` permanently in the `.Rprofile` file (see `?Startup` for details)

Answer (score 2):

I know this was solved years ago, but I've just come across it and realised that there is a bit more to this if you use the `body()` function.

The raw function has only the one attribute, `"srcref"` which contains the code of the function, along with it's own attributes and class of `"srcref"` (which dictates how it'll get printed).

The `body()` of a function, such as `body(util.add)` has three attributes.

- `"srcref"` which contains the body of the function stored as a list of expressions.
- `"srcfile"` which contains the source file of the function (which is what you are looking for in this question)
- `"wholeSrcref"` which points to the entire source file.

This gives you an alternative (although slightly slower) method to extract the source file name `attr(body(util.add),"srcfile")`, along with being able to see (although not interact with) the *sibling* functions (i.e. the other functions loaded in the same source file).

Not sure if it's useful, but it could be interesting.

Let's also not forget about the `%@%` infix operator for accessing attributes using the `{purrr}` package, with this we could use the more succinct (although again, slower) piece of code as:
`util.add%@%srcref%@%srcfile`