# How to find the file where a function is defined?

Tags: r

The question's title pretty much says it all.

The solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32749240/559827) doesn't always work.  E.g.,

```
> class(facet_grid)
[1] "function"
> attr(facet_grid, "srcref")
NULL
> attributes(facet_grid)
NULL
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but generally speaking you won't be able to directly determine the specific file a function is defined in, esp. since a function doesn't *need* to be defined in a file (you could define it directly in the console). The only reason this is possible in the other answer is because calling `source('some/file.R')` provides `source` with the information it needs to create an object of class `srcref` (namely, the file path).

Comment: Even if you are able to narrow things down to which package provides the function, there is no guarantee that `some_function` is defined in a file named `some_function.R`, so most likely you will need to grep for `"some_function <- function"` in that package's directory, etc..

Comment: Please indicate in the question why you need this information.

Comment: **a.** If you just want the source code for a function, just type the name without the parentheses in the console, e.g. `facet_grid`. **b** If you really need the actual source for a function from a package, you can use [MetaCRAN](https://github.com/cran) to search and find [a copy](https://github.com/cran/ggplot2/blob/f5b44da50369016c92e3b9e31f85b4e1b30f739b/man/facet_grid.Rd). Or just google it and you'll probably find the original repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The environment()-function will return the package in which a function is "located" after it is loaded.

```
> environment(facet_grid)
<environment: namespace:ggplot2>
```

After downloading ggplot2_version_whatever.tag.gz from CRAN (or perhaps github) and expanding it, you can find (using your system text search facilities) a file named facet-grid.r that has  this definiton starting at line 125:

```
facet_grid <- function(facets, margins = FALSE, scales = "fixed", space = "fixed", shrink = TRUE, labeller = "label_value", as.table = TRUE, switch = NULL, drop = TRUE) {
```

You should find more comments. Comments are dropped during compiling unless you make special efforts to retain them.

Comment: It's not obvious to me how one gets from the value returned by `environment` to the path to the file where the function is defined.

Comment: Use `.libPaths()` to find the location of your packages.

Comment: I know where my packages are installed.  I still cannot find where `facet_grid` is defined.

Comment: @kjo You need to search the package source code. R doesn't know or care in which file the source code of a function was defined.

Comment: If you want the sources for a ggplot2 function you will need to go to CRAN for the tar.gz file. Most people install the binary package rather than going for a source-install: Google search produces this fairly quickly: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/ggplot2_2.1.0.tar.gz