# In R how can I find in which file is a function defined

Tags: r

when I develop a package I find myself trying to find in which file is a function defined.

Say I some R file (of a package `my_package`) I see

```
fun <- myFun(...)
{
  # some stuff
  test <- someOtherFunction(...)
}
```

Is there an easy way to find in which file the function `someOtherFunction` is defined ?
Something like `findFunction(name='someOtherFunction', package='my_package')`

Comment: I think this is a functionality of the editor/IDE you use, rather than `r` itself. You should retag the question accordingly

Comment: I deliberately want an answer that is not Rstudio or other iDE related

Comment: Do you mean something like what's described in [this post?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32749240/9374673)

Comment: @MihaiChelaru looks exactly like that but does not seem to be working at all on functions from my package

Comment: Maybe you can use the wonderful `getAnywhere` function? Try `getAnywhere(someOtherFunction)`.

Comment: @ekstroem never knew that existed, thanks for introducing me to that!

Comment: @ekstroem, thank you. Note: perhaps you can put this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to open the file in Rstudio in a quicker way.
You can use the Rstudio `Go to file/function...` to open a file that contains a function. This is useful when you have custom function written in a file or navigating around the modules.
Scroll to the tab `Code`

```
Code --> Go to file/function...
```

and enter the function name to locate the file with that function and open it.

You can use the default shortcut provided `Ctrl+.` or alternatively using the `Tools` tab `Modify Keyboard Shortcuts` and set up something it `Ctrl O`.