# Source code references (srcref) for loaded packages and objects in workspace

Tags: r, error-handling

I want get a "list" for

- all loaded packages and
- all objects in the workspace

together with the information if the source code is available for these packages/objects
(`srcref` attribute).

How can I do this (mainly how do source code references work with packages, do I really have to "scan" the attributes of each object in the package)?

Background: I want the inform the user that source may be missing when errors occur so that diagnosing the problem may be more difficult (no file names and line numbers available).

Expected result:

Eg. a `data.frame` with these columns:

1. Package name (empty or "global" for workspace objects)
2. Object name (may be empty, if there is no need to examine all package objects)
3. Has_source_references (boolean)

So far my code (partly based on the comment of @mnist - TXH!):

```
objs <- lapply(search(), function(p) {
                            print(p)
                            objs <- ls(p)
                            res <- if (length(objs) > 0 & !(p %in% c("package:base"))) data.frame(objs = objs, pkg = sub("package:", "", p), stringsAsFactors = F) else data.frame(objs = character(0), pkg = character(0))
                            return(res)
                          } )
all.objs <- do.call(rbind, objs)
# This does not work: I try to get the srcref of every object. No srcref means no source code
all.objs$srcref <- attr(mget(all.objs$objs, inherits = T), "srcref")
```

`srcref` references:

- `?srcfile`
- https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2010-2/RJournal_2010-2_Murdoch.pdf

Comment: I am not really sure what your expected result is. Could you provide a single example?

Comment: @mnist I have updated my question. I mean the problem for me is not to loop over all objects and attributes but to find someone with enough experience to show a reliable way to identify existing source code (references) since `srcrefs` documentation is rare

Comment: Are you aware of `search()` in combination with `ls()`? `check <- lapply(search(), ls);
names(check) <- search()`. And can you proceed from this via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32749240/8107362)?

Comment: @mnist THX, listing all first-order objects is the first part of an answer. Nested objects are still hidden, eg. objects within environments (`e <- new.env(); e$f <- function() invisible(); ls(".GlobalEnv")` does list `e`, but not `f`. But this is the gold standard ;-) Your link reminded me that checking only one object per package for an existing `srcref` attribute should suffice until something weird was done in the package...